# One Windows 7 pc slows down when another pc is turned on

Tags: windows-7, networking, performance

I have a very strange problem that is affecting only 1 computer of the network (a network composed of 6pcs and two network printers): 
If I turn on pc number ONE first, and pc number TWO after that, pc ONE slows down to a crawl. 
I don't mean that the network speed is slow, I mean that the entire pc slows down, with a jerky mouse cursor. Both machines have Windows 7 professional with most recent updates. I have already reinstalled the O.S. on computer TWO, and have scanned computer ONE for viruses/trojans/malware, but nothing was found. I have also changed computer name and IP on computer TWO. What I can see is that there seems to be a lot of network traffic between the two pcs, but what could be causing it even after I have changed the IP and name of one of the pcs? PC ONE slows down as soon as pc TWO displays the logon screen, even if the user is not logged in.
Any idea how to troubleshoot this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you mapped any drives on PC1?

Comment: No, there are no network shares between the two pcs. And I have already changed the network name of pc 1, so even if there was a network share, it shouldn't connect to that pc...